# play! Uploaded images not visible in production mode

Tags: java, scala, nginx, playframework, akka-http

Hi guys I'm new to play framework,

Qun 1:

what I wanted in my server is Users can upload images, and see uploaded images in web page,
when I run the server in Dev mode everything is works fine (I can upload and see the images in web page),
but I try do this same thing in production mode, uploading works fine(images saved in public directory) but images are not visible in web page...!

my twirl html template:

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.versioned(public/file1.png)" width=25% height=auto alt="file1.png">
```

routes:

```
GET        /versionedAssets/*file        controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

browser's Elements page (F12):

```
<img src="/versionedAssets/file1.png" width="25%" height="auto" alt="file1.png">
```

I can even show the image using NGINX (passing image location as an url) successfully,
but why i can't see the image in play's production mode?,
I don't even have clue about what part I did wrong.!
please help me if you know anything about it.!

Qun 2:

Is that possible to serve our app without frontend server like NGINX, etc.
because play already running in AkkaHttpServer.

Comment: At which URL can you see the image? At which URL is your page displayed?

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question: no need for Nginx indeed.

Comment: @GaëlJ page displayed in localhost:9000/file after uploading the image it's also shown in the same page

Comment: why 'public/file1.png' in '@routes.Assets.versioned(public/file1.png)'? You already defined 'public' directory in 'controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaStream)
I've  found `Ok.SendFile()` method used to serving files, then I've created a method in controller

```
    def getImageFromPath()= Action{ implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
Ok.sendFile(new java.io.File("/path/to/file")) }
```

then added route in routes file

```
  GET     /getimage        controllers.ImageController.getImageFromPath()
```

reverse routing in Twirl template

```
  <img src="@routes.ImageController.getImageFromPath()" width=25% height=auto alt="file1.png">
```

helped me to solve this issue..!